# Co occurrence plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm very very new to R. I have a csv file that looks like

```
A   B   C   D
A1   a   v   a
A2   v   v   a
A3   a   a   a
```

I'd like to make a `co occurrence plot` using it but I couldn't figure out how to plot it when the input has characters and not numbers.

I tried using a few packages (I couldn't get any of them to work), out of which one is `cooccur`. It gave me the following error `"Error in rowSums(spp_site_mat, na.rm = T) : 'x' must be numeric"`.
I'd really really appreciate if you point me toward anything helpful or give any code suggestions.

EDIT:

Rows would have the values from column A, columns would be their corresponding values, "a" and "v" something as shown in this [link](http://userguide.dedoose.com/images/Frequency-table.jpg).

[image]

Also I have hundreds of columns so I cannot change each column to numeric using `as.numeric(table$B)`

Comment: So what would this plot look like? Do you have a link to an example with categorical data?

Comment: @MrFlick Please find the edited question. I will put up sample file data in a minute.

Comment: So what you seem to be describing isn't a plot at all, just a table?

Comment: @MrFlick I need something like this: "http://userguide.dedoose.com/images/Frequency-table.jpg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `table` each row to count the unique values and then form a matrix using use `rbind.fill`. You can then plot using `geom_tile` adding in the counts as labels.

```
# your data
dat <- read.table(text="A   B   C   D
A1   a   v   a
A2   v   v   a
A3   a   a   a", header=TRUE)


library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# transform your data 
mat <- rbind.fill.matrix(apply(dat[-1], 1, function(i) t(as.matrix(table(i)))))
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0
rownames(mat) <- dat$A

# plot   
ggplot(melt(mat), aes(Var2, Var1, fill=value)) + 
                 geom_tile() +
                 scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(0,3), low="white") +
                 geom_text( aes(label=value))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

About the code

```
mat <- rbind.fill.matrix(apply(dat[-1], 1, function(i) t(as.matrix(table(i)))))
```

Starting from the inside

```
apply(dat[-1], 1, function(i) t(as.matrix(table(i))))
```

`apply` with `MARGIN = 1` applies the function across the rows of the data, excluding the first column. The aim of the function  is to table the values for each row. `as.matrix` is used to change the format of the output and the `t` (transpose) changes the orientation of the matrix. (Most likely a more succinct way to do this)

As there may not be the same values in each row (row 3 has no v's) all values will not be represented in each table - so `rbind` will not work. `rbind.fill` from `plyr` package fills in with `NA`.

Below replaces the missing (`NA`) with zero

```
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you briefly say what 'mat <- rbind.fill.matrix(apply(dat[-1], 1, function(i) t(as.matrix(table(i)))))' this line does. Thank you!